# Get post ID before add_theme_support

Tags: hooks, add-theme-support

I need to enable font sizes options in editor with `add_theme_support`, but only for the specific post types and page templates.

To distinct them, I need to get the post ID in the WP admin, before `add_theme_support` gets executed.

The problem is that hook I am using is `after_setup_theme`, and seems like page ID is not initialized at the time this hook fires.

Is there some other hook I can use for `add_theme_support` ? Or is there a way to somehow get the post ID during  `after_setup_theme` ?

P.s. `$_REQUEST['post']` wont work because I need the ID when creating a new post as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to add support for the font sizes options to specific post types and page templates in the WordPress admin.